# Is there a way to read an XLSX file from a URL in Java?

Tags: java

I have a url that when hit will download a XLSX spreadsheet onto my browser.

Is there a way to dynamically access this URL and read the contents of the XLSX file?

I have tried a solution but I get an error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office Open XML) file
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.getPartsImpl(ZipPackage.java:286)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.getParts(OPCPackage.java:756)
    at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:327)
    at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:37)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:295)
    at TestRead.main(TestRead.java:27)
```

```
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class TestRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {

        String urlStr = "https:/someurl/listing.xlsx";
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);
        URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
        uc.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(uc.getInputStream());
    }
}
```

Comment: Dump the inputstream into a file and see what it contains. Could well just be a redirect to another link which contains the actual spreadsheet.

Comment: There is java code here to download file from URL: https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url

Comment: I see no issue in your code. Are you sure that the URL returns a valid xlsx file? Try to download it with wget or curl and check if you can open it with MS Office.

Comment: @EmrahDiril That seems like an unnecessarily verbose way to do what [Files.copy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) does in one line of code.

Comment: @VGR yup I forgot about `Files.copy`. That's much better